# Time difference between normal build and docker image build

Tags: reactjs, docker, build, dockerfile

When building a react nginx project as a docker image, it takes about 8 minutes.

The npm run build command takes up most of the execution time.
So, to reduce the build time, we used esbuild to shorten the build time and optimized the dockerfile through multi stage build.

A normal build of a react project (npm run build) takes only 30 seconds, but if you build a docker image, it still takes about 500 seconds, most of which is spent on npm run build.

Is there a way to reduce docker image build time?
For reference, the Docker image size is about 60mb.

Also, this is the dockerfile content I used.

I don't know why there is such a big difference between the normal build and Docker image build times.

```
FROM node:16.11.0-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i --legacy-peer-deps

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# run stage
FROM nginx:1.23-alpine

CMD [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env-creator.sh && nginx -g 'daemon off;'" ]

ENV REACT_APP_API_MIN_DATE_NUM="1"  \
    REACT_APP_API_MIN_DATE_UNIT="year"

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build .

COPY .env .

COPY --chmod=0755 ./env-creator.sh .


RUN apk add --no-cache bash

EXPOSE 80
```